# Cloudfront Default Root Objects within Sub-directories of an s3 Origin Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

With AWS Cloudfront it is possible [to specify a Default Root Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html):

> When you define a default root object, an end-user request that calls
>   the root of your distribution returns the default root object. For
>   example, if you designate the file index.html as your default root
>   object, a request for:
>
> http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/
>
> Returns:
>
> http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/index.html

**If Cloudfront is hosting [an S3 origin bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#concept_S3Origin) then is it possible to specify a default root object for each sub-directory?**

As an example, accessing the sub-resource

```
http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/subresource
```

Would actually return

```
http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/subresource/index.html
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with the help of Lambda@Edge.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/